# Monkey patching scope: Outside function doesn't affect ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, monkeypatching

I'm trying to patch some `I18n` methods to test correct escaping. Doing this in a test, and it goes something like:

```
test "JS files should be using correct escaping" do
  module I18n
    def self.t(*args)
      %q{a JS interpolation ' " test}
    end
  end
  filename = Rails.root + "app/assets/some_file.js.erb"
  erb = ERB.new(File.read(filename))
  result = erb.run
end
```

At this point, all of the `I18n.t` calls within `some_file.js.erb` are indeed replaced... but with *correct* values from the I18n files, not with `a JS interpolation ' " test`.

In other words, the monkey patch doesn't take hold inside of ERB. Is there a way for me to make this work?

Comment: Is `I18n` referencing `::I18n` in that context or some `Whatever::I18n`?

Comment: I did not redefine I18n anywhere else. Should I go `module ::I18n`?

Comment: Worth a shot. I don't know what context that `module I18n` is executed in.

Comment: Okay, going `::I18n` totally fixed it! Wanna put that into an answer? Would love to to accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There you go. The implicit hierarchy in the namespacing can be confusing and trying to figure out why it doesn't work can be terribly frustrating,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your `module I18n` isn't actually opening `::I18n`, that's probably executed in an unexpected context so you're actually opening the `SomethingUnexpected::I18n` module for some `SomethingUnexpected` that's part of the test framework.

The easiest way around that is to explicitly state that you want to work in the top level namespace:

```
module ::I18n
  #...
end
```